# How can I return a percentage in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I'm having troubles how to properly return a percentage in PHP.  I've tried using the sprintf function, although this only worked when I used decimals; how can I return a percentage in PHP using built in functions?

```
$percentage = sprintf('%3f', $completes / $incompletes);
```

Does not work.  I've tried everything I could think of and all though this worked for decimals, it doesn't appear to work for integers...

Comment: %% - Returns a percent sign

Comment: $percentage = sprintf('%3f%%', $completes / $incompletes);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
$percentage = ($completes / $incompletes) * 100;
echo $percentage . "%";
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  idk why sprintf wasn't working, im really tired not to have thought of this myself..

Answer (score 1):

**%% - Returns a percent sign**

```
$percentage = sprintf('%3f%%', $completes / $incompletes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$percentage = sprintf("%01.3f", $completes / $incompletes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$percentage = number_format($completes / $incompletes, 3) . '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, **[live demo](https://eval.in/793588)**.

```
<?php
   echo sprintf('%.2f%%', 177.3333 / 100.0);
```